# Have to start Android child services also in foreground?

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions

In my Android app, I record a lot of things like GPS, barometric pressure, Bluetooth sensors. There is a "super" service which is started in the foreground:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, DataCollectorService.class);
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intent);
```

The service itself has to start numerous child services like GPS-recording, Bluetooth sensor recording and the like. And the service creates a notification:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // . . . 
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            // . . .
            .build();

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    mHandler.postDelayed(this::startChildServices, 100);
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void startChildServices() {
    // . . .
    if (gpsEnabled) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GpsTrackingService.class);
        bindService(intent, mGpsServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(intent);
    }
    if (isPressureEnabled) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PressureService.class);
        bindService(intent, pressureConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(intent);
    }
    // . . .
}
```

All works well, but a very small percentage of the users encounter crashes like this:

android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()

Actually, I start the "super" service in the foreground, as you can see.

**Do I have to start the child services in the foreground as well?**

Obviously, I don't want to have 3-7 notification icons in the users status bar.

Comment: "The service itself has to start numerous child services" -- why? Why is this not just one service that tracks your data? What value to the user is there in having multiple services?

Comment: @CommonsWare this is a good question. The child services are designed to function independently of the data-collector-service. They are controlled by the Android service lifecycle. It could be possible to refactor them into simple business classes, but then they would need a wrapper to be used independently.

Comment: IMHO, reorganizing along those lines is much better than trying to have multiple independent services. UI development is moving towards a single activity and multiple fragments, where the activity is basically the OS component that says "I have UI in the foreground" that orchestrates the fragments. Similarly, your one service should be the OS component that says "I am in the foreground without a UI", and your per-task work would be in ordinary classes orchestrated by that service.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose there are some bugs in Android regarding "not started in foreground". The problem with the crash happens only in much less than 1% of the cases. I have the feeling of doing ~30% of my work just for boilerplate and SDK changes.